# PIP can't install PyTorch on Windows 10

Tags: python, pip, module, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to run:
`pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117`

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch
```

Running following commands prints:

1. `pip3 --version`                       -->  `pip 23.1.2 from C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)`
2. `python3 --version`               --> `Python 3.10.6`
3. `python3 -m pip --version` --> `pip 23.1.2 from C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)`

Trying to run `python3 -m pip install ...` doesn't change anything.

I would really appreciate some help!